# How to apply transition on transform translateX

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

How I can apply a transition on `transform: translateX` CSS property in Vue?

I've tried in this way but it doesn't work, I want to have a smooth slide in/out effect when the menu is opened or closed. I'm using Vue and Bootstrap.

```
<transition name="slide">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse position-fixed" :class="{ 'show': isVisible }" ref="menuLinks">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
                <a class="nav-link" :href="item.link">{{ item.title }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</transition>
```

```
//CSS
.navbar-collapse {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 25%;
    background:white;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2em;
    transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.slide-enter-active, .slide-enter {
    //to do animation soft
    transition: transform 1s linear;
    animation: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.slide-leave-active, .slide-leave-to {
    transition: transform 1s linear;
    animation: slideOut;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {
        transform: transaletX(-100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: transaletX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've removed the transition from `.slide-leave-active` as suggested but nothing change

```
.slide-enter-active, .slide-enter {
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    animation: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.slide-leave-active, .slide-leave-to {
    animation: slideOut;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your slideIn animation "transaletX" should be "translateX"

Comment: damn, thanks I didn't noticed that :)

Comment: @Chrillewoodz fixed the typo but seems not work

Comment: Remove your transitions, the animation will take care of the transition.

Comment: where I need to remove the transitions? from the main element or from the vue transition classes?In vue docs they used a transition to have a smmoth effect

Comment: Inside the `.slide-leave-active` styles

Comment: I need to test, I will let you know